# Using pagination with a filtered results, doesn't work

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a Class Based View with pagination:

```
class ItemListView(ListView)
   paginate_by= 10
```

By default is working ok.

Example: for 100 items, in database pagination will be:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

In a normal site users, use search, and in some cases the search is also paginated.

The search is done overwriting get_queryset.

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

   if self.request.GET.get('q'):
            qs = qs.objects.filter(keyword=self.request.GET.get('q'))
```

In template I have:

```
   <li>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.number}}">&raquo;</a>
        </li>
```

My issues, is when I click on the `search listing` second page, it goes to the 'full list' pagination.

So, the `page_object` is ignoring the 'initial queryset' and is doing its own default queryset.

Example: the filtered queryset has 2 items, so should be 2 pages:

For the first pages, is correct:

```
1,2
```

Click on the link to second page, and I have, and should be 1,2 :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: on second page you see whole list or pagination is ok but the filter doesn't work?

Comment: @aliva, hi I updated the quetions, with examples; the pagination looks ok, but the filter doesn't work

Comment: Don't you need to pass the search query along with the url of the next pages too, like `?page={{ page_obj.number}}&q=...`

Comment: I thought about that, but shouln't paginate_object contain the initial queryset otherwise how is doing the pagination ?